# Server not running with pg and postgresql on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, postgresql, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I need some help with this setup on ruby on rails:

*ruby version 2.7.1
ruby on rails version 6.0.3.3*

In my application gemfile I have:

*gem 'postgres'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.19.0'*

But, when I run 'bundle install' and I will try to run the server, the following message appears:

*This is an old, deprecated version of the Ruby PostgreSQL driver that hasn't
been maintained or supported since early 2008.*

Comment: try removing version specified in gemfile `gem 'pg'` and then `bundle update pg`  then try `bundle install` is you have specified any thing like `gem 'postgres'` then try removing it.

Comment: nice input. when I removed the ''gem postgres" and the version of ''gem pg'', the server works. thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

try to install using command **gem 'pg'** without specifying the version.